# Unknown behaviour of StringBuffer.append()

Tags: java, stringbuffer

Weird behaviour of  `StringBuffer.append()`:
[javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-stringbuffer-capacity-method) states:

> If the number of the character increases from its current capacity, it > increases the capacity by (oldcapacity*2)+2.

It can be demonstrated by following code:

```
class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                sb.append("abcdef"); // 16;
                System.out.println(sb.capacity());

                sb.append("1234561711"); // 34
                System.out.println(sb.capacity()); // 34
        }
}
```

But, it shows weird behaviour in following code:

```
class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                sb.append("abcdef"); // 16;
                System.out.println(sb.capacity());

                sb.append("12345617111111111111111111111111111111"); // 44 total 44 character in sb, so capacity should be 70 as it goes from 16, 34, 70, 142 etc.
                System.out.println(sb.capacity()); // 34
        }
}
```

*if we use two append with above characters the capacity will be 70*!
So, I think only one limit breaks in one `append()`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Do you have a question?

Comment: I would recommend using a canonical source of documentation, e.g. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#ensureCapacity(int)).

Comment: The capacity obviously can't be 34 in the second case, if the total length is 44. http://ideone.com/Ob76lJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logic of `StringBuffer`'s `ensureCapacity` is stated in the Javadoc:

> **[void java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacity(int minimumCapacity)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#ensureCapacity(int))**
>
> Ensures that the capacity is at least equal to the specified minimum.If the current capacity is less than the argument, then a new internal array is allocated with greater capacity. The new capacity is the larger of:
>
> • The minimumCapacity argument.
>
> • Twice the old capacity, plus 2.

In your second snippet, 44 (which is the minimum required capacity, since after the second `append` there will be 44 characters in the `StringBuffer`) is larger than twice the old capacity, plus 2 (which is 34). Hence the new capacity is 44.